# How to run codes on background thread in Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I'm using incremental loading to show a `ListView` items. I run `LoadDetails` method in the background thread using `Task.Run(...)` to not busy the UI thread.

But it still blocks the UI thread and it doesn't render UI elements until it finishes the task.

executing LoadDetails method takes around 3 seconds to complete.

```
private async void LoadItemCounts(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Phase != 6)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not in phase 6");
    }

    var item = args.Item as ItemModel;

    var templateRoot = (Grid)args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot;
    var textBlock = (TextBlock)templateRoot.FindName("textBlock");

    await Task.Run(() => LoadDetails(textBlock, item.Id));
}

private async Task LoadDetails(TextBlock textBlock, string id)
{
    int count = await DataSource.GetItemCounts(id);

    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            textBlock.Text = count.ToString();
        });
}
```

How to fix this so it doesn't block the UI thread? thanks.

*(It's a Windows Phone Runtime app)*

Comment: Not sure why that would block the UI thread, but in `LoadItemAcounts` you should just `await LoadDetails(textBlock, item.Id)`, you should not create a Task to synchronously call an async method.

Comment: @BenRobinson I did that to execute `LoadDetails` on a background thread as it is stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994635.aspx)  as a way to have a responsive UI. however tried without creating a task and nothing changed.

Comment: How Complex is your templateRoot? A possible problem could be 
    var textBlock = (TextBlock)templateRoot.FindName("textBlock");
Maybe the search for the UI element with the name "textBlock" is taking to long.
Use the "Performance and Diagnostics" tool in Visual Studio to see what is eating up your cpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question how you are measuring the 3 second delay. Is it that the call to `GetItemCounts()` itself takes 3 seconds? If so, isn't that to be expected? The delay is why you would execute that asynchronously in the first place, isn't it?

The code you posted doesn't really seem quite right. Since your new `Task` doesn't `await` the call to `LoadDetails()`, that task will finish right away, without any synchronization with the actual work being done. Written differently, you could also avoid having to call through the `Dispatcher` directly.

I would have written it something more like this:

```
private async void LoadItemCounts(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Phase != 6)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not in phase 6");
    }

    var item = args.Item as ItemModel;

    var templateRoot = (Grid)args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot;
    var textBlock = (TextBlock)templateRoot.FindName("textBlock");

    await LoadDetails(textBlock, item.Id);
}

private async Task LoadDetails(TextBlock textBlock, string id)
{
    int count = await DataSource.GetItemCounts(id);

    textBlock.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

I.e. as long as you keep awaiting on the UI thread, you don't need to invoke via the `Dispatcher`. Note that the above assumes you need the `LoadDetails()` method, presumably because you call it from multiple places and some require this particular implementation for some reason. But note that you could have just written the `LoadItemCounts()` method like this, and left out the `LoadDetails()` method altogether:

```
private async void LoadItemCounts(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Phase != 6)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not in phase 6");
    }

    var item = args.Item as ItemModel;

    var templateRoot = (Grid)args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot;
    var textBlock = (TextBlock)templateRoot.FindName("textBlock");

    textBlock.Text = (await DataSource.GetItemCounts(id)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is correctly not blocking the UI thread by using await, but since  `LoadItemDetails()` is presumably being called on the UI thread, it won't finish until the method is finished doing its work.

To fix this, just omit the `await` on the call to `Task.Run()`, so something like

```
Task.Run(() => LoadDetails(textBlock, item.Id));
```

should make `LoadItemDetails()` return immediately.